# Do I need to include prior probability when plotting probability in R?

Tags: r, statistics, classification, bayesian

Is the wrong or am I overthinking?

For a binary classification problem {0, 1} with 1 predictor X. The prior probability of being in class 0 is = 0.6 and the density function is standard normal f0(x) = Normal (0,1)

The density function for X in class 1 is also normal but with mean = 1 and variance = 0.5. f1(x) = Normal (1, 0.5)

and I need to plot priorprobabilityf0(x) and priorprobailityf1(x) into the same figure.

This is what I have written in R but I cant seem to work out if I was meant to include the prior probabilities.

```
x <- seq(-5, 5, length=200)
y <- dnorm(x, mean= 0, sd=1)

t = sqrt(0.5)

z <- seq(-5, 5, length=200)
a <- dnorm(x, mean=1, sd=t)

plot(z, a, type="l", lwd=2, col='red', xlim = c(-5,5), ylim = c(0,0.65),  xlab = "Observed Value", ylab = "Probability Density")
lines(x,y, col='blue', lwd=2)
```

Comment: If so how would I go about including it in R?

Comment: Maybe probability and counter probability `abline(v=.6, lty=2)` and `abline(v=1 - .6, lty=2)`?